# Html and VBscript code to save results to local file

Tags: html, vbscript

I am trying to create a simple Html page which takes 7 inputs and saves it to a excel file  every time submit button is clicked(already saved locally and all 7 headers set).I found a VBscript code on internet which seems to be fine but isn't working on clicking submit.
Please help! Thanks in advance.
VBscript:

```
    <script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">  
      Sub Saveit()  
      Dim iRow 
      Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel. Application")  
      Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open ("D:\Users\mylaptop\Desktop\test.xlsx")  
      objExcel.Application.Visible = True  
      ObjWorkbook.Windows (1).Visible = True  
      Set XlSheet =objWorkbook.Sheets (1)  
      XlSheet.Activate  
      iRow = 1  
      With objExcel  
          Do while .Cells (iRow, 1).value <> ""  
              .Cells (iRow, 1).activate  
               iRow = iRow + 1  
          Loop  
             .Cells (iRow, 1).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("var1") (0).Value  
             .Cells (iRow, 2).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("op1") (0).Value  
             .Cells (iRow, 3).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("var2") (0).Value  
             .Cells (iRow, 4).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("logic") (0).Value  
             .Cells (iRow, 5).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("var3") (0).Value
             .Cells (iRow, 6).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("op2") (0).Value
             .Cells (iRow, 7).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("var4") (0).Value  
             MsgBox "Data Added Successfully”, vbinformation  
             Document.GetElementsByName ("var1") (0).Value=""  
             Document.GetElementsByName ("op1") (0).Value=""  
             Document.GetElementsByName ("var2") (0).Value=""  
             Document.GetElementsByName ("logic") (0).Value=""  
             Document.GetElementsByName ("var3") (0).Value=""  
             Document.GetElementsByName ("op2") (0).Value=""  
             Document.GetElementsByName ("var4") (0).Value=""  
         End With  
         ObjWorkbook. Save  
         ObjWorkbook. Close  
         Set objWorkbook = Nothing  
         Set objExcel = Nothing  
     End Sub  
  </script>
```

Html code:

```
    Variable 1:   <br>
     <input type="text" name="var1" Value=""><br>  
     Operator 1:    <br>
     <input type="text" name="op1" Value=""><br>  
     Var 2/Value :      <br>
     <input type="text" name="var2" Value=""><br>  
     Logic gate :       <br>
     <input type="text" name="logic" Value=""><br>  
     Variable 3:   <br>
     <input type="text" name="var3" Value=""><br>  
     Operator 2:    <br>
     <input type="text" name="op2" Value=""><br>  
     Var 4/ Value :     <br>
     <input type="text" name="var4" Value=""><br> 
     <br>  
     <input type="button" onclick="Saveit()" value="Submit" /><br>
```

Comment: This does not work with "normal" HTML. Browsers do not have access to the file system, therefore you cannot read or write any files. Additionally, VBScript is only supported in Internet Explorer <=11. If you want to keep using VBScript and HTML, try creating a [HTML Application (HTA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Hey @Tomalak Thanks for help. I created a HTA file and tried running it but got this error: **ActiveX component can't create object: Excel.Application** . Please help further. Thanks!!

Comment: I can only Google for that error message, just like you. One thought: It's possible that Windows puts security restrictions on downloaded files. If you have downloaded the HTA, try to create a new one from scratch in a text editor. If you have written the HTA yourself, try creating an `Excel.Application` object in a regular VBS file. If that does **not** work, this means some part of Excel is not correctly installed. Search for the error message and try the suggestions you find. If it works in VBS, it should also work in the HTA.